# C# Numad enter vs. Normal Enter

Tags: c#, input, keyboard

I was wondering if there was an easy way in C#, to determent when the normal enter key is pressed or when the numpad enter key is pressed. My program currently has a properties of the type System.Input.Windows.Key where the Enter key is stored.

Now I want to do something when the user presses the Numpad Enter key. Currently I'm using a low level keyboard hook that fires an event when the key is pressed.

When ever I press either of the 2 enter keys the same keys gets returned for both.

Any solution?

Comment: I personally think there is no solution if you want to use System.Windows.Input.Key. How about enter+alt and just enter?

Comment: Changing the buttons is not really an option. It has to be ONLY the numpad enter. It doesnt have to be Input.Key. It can be somethings else, what is a good alternative than?

Comment: Is that console application and input is passing by console? If not, consider using System.Windows.Forms.Key enumeration I think (not sure) that one of this enters is "Return" and the other is "Enter" in this enumeration.